# Am getting org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException in many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to use JBoss Tools 4.1 Hibernate plugin for the sake of fast production . but I'm getting an exception at the first leg .

First of all physical DB tables are as follows :

```
 describe Teams ; 
 Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                         
 ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
 NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
 COUNTRY                        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)   

 describe players;
 Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
 ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
 NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
 NATIONALITY                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 

describe player_team;
Name                           Null     Type 
PLAYER_ID                      NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
TEAM_ID                        NOT NULL NUMBER
```

Entities are as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYERS")
public class Players implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal id;
private String name;
private String nationality;
private Set<PlayerTeam> playerTeams = new HashSet<PlayerTeam>(0);

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

@Column(name = "NATIONALITY", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getNationality() {
    return this.nationality;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "players")
public Set<PlayerTeam> getPlayerTeams() {
    return this.playerTeams;
}
  // setters go here but i deleted for readability 

 }


 @Entity
 @Table(name = "TEAMS")
 public class Teams implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal id;
private String name;
private String country;
private Set<PlayerTeam> playerTeams = new HashSet<PlayerTeam>(0);   

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "COUNTRY", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getCountry() {
    return this.country;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teams")
public Set<PlayerTeam> getPlayerTeams() {
    return this.playerTeams;
}

   // setters go here

 }

  @Embeddable
  public class PlayerTeamId implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal playerId;
private BigDecimal teamId;

@Column(name = "PLAYER_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getPlayerId() {
    return this.playerId;
}

public void setPlayerId(BigDecimal playerId) {
    this.playerId = playerId;
}

@Column(name = "TEAM_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getTeamId() {
    return this.teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(BigDecimal teamId) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
}

public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ((this == other))
        return true;
    if ((other == null))
        return false;
    if (!(other instanceof PlayerTeamId))
        return false;
    PlayerTeamId castOther = (PlayerTeamId) other;

    return ((this.getPlayerId() == castOther.getPlayerId()) || (this
    .getPlayerId() != null && castOther.getPlayerId() != null && this   
            .getPlayerId().equals(castOther.getPlayerId())))
            && ((this.getTeamId() == castOther.getTeamId()) || (this
                    .getTeamId() != null && 
       castOther.getTeamId() != null && this                              
       .getTeamId().equals(castOther.getTeamId())));
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;

    result = 37 * result
            + (getPlayerId() == null ? 0 :  
        this.getPlayerId().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result
            + (getTeamId() == null ? 0 : this.getTeamId().hashCode());
    return result;
}

  }
```

And then i tried to insert records at join table as follows :

```
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();       
    Players pl = (Players) session.load(Players.class, new BigDecimal(2));
    Teams tm = (Teams) session.load(Teams.class, new BigDecimal(25));
    PlayerTeam pt = new PlayerTeam();
    pt.setPlayers(pl);
    pt.setTeams(tm);
    session.save(pt);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

winded up getting the following exception :

```
 org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class    
 business.PlayerTeam
```

Finally hibernate.cfg.xml

```
  <session-factory name="se">
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property  
     name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">LECTURE1</property>
    <property      
     name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">lecture1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">LECTURE1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect</property>
    <mapping class="business.Players" />
     <mapping class="business.PlayerTeam" />
    <mapping class="business.Teams" />
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 </session-factory>

 Would you throw some light on this please ? thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every entity in Hibernate requires an ID column annotated with `@Id`.  Your `PlayerTeam` class doesn't have such a column.  If your `PlayerTeam` class is simply a join table, it doesn't even need to be an entity.  You can simply do:

```
public class Players {

...

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="players", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Teams> teams;

...

}

public class Teams {

...

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="player_team", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TEAM_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PLAYER_ID")})
private list<Players> players;

...

}
```

This will setup a bidirectional many-to-many relationship with the Teams class as the owning side.  You can then get rid of the `PlayerTeamId` class entirely.

As an aside, I highly recommend your class names be singular (e.g. Player and Team instead of Players and Teams)

Comment: I know how to do it without joint table . But as i said in my question i want to use JBoss tools plugin . JBoss generates 2 extra classes . JBoss plugin already generated @EmbeddedId annotation at the TeamPlayer class . so it is supposed to be working . http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: So, from the example you linked to, "The Hibernate / JBoss tools generated annotation codes are not working in this third table extra column scenario. To make it works, you should customize the code to use “@AssociationOverride“, in StockCategory.java to represent the many to many relationship.".  Have you tried using @AssociationOverride?  I personally think this tool is creating an overly complicated entity structure and that is going to cause you headaches down the road.  I woul have expected the tool to simply generate the direct @ManyToMany.

Comment: I didn't pay too much attention to  @AssociationOverride . Now after applied it, It works . thanks sir